# Adding options to existing Q_PROPERTY from base class only in dereived class

Tags: c++, qt5, qmetaobject

I have a very simple base class which defines a normal Q_PROPERTY with READ and NOTIFY (WRITE is not in all dereived implementations possible).

```
class BaseClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList someEntries READ someEntries NOTIFY someEntriesChanged)

public:
    explicit BaseClass(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}

    virtual QStringList someEntries() const = 0;

    void processEntries() {
        for(auto entry : someEntries()) {
            //process entry
        }
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void someEntriesChanged(const QStringList &someEntries);
};
```

Now I have 2 dereiving classes, of which one supports only one entry (`SingleItem`) and the other one supports multiple entries (`MultiItem`).

`SingleItem` converts the one QString-member to a QStringList when requested and allows setting it using the differently called property (`theEntry`):

```
class SingleItem : public BaseClass {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString theEntry READ theEntry WRITE setTheEntry NOTIFY theEntryChanged);

public:
    explicit SingleItem(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : BaseClass(parent) {}
    virtual ~SingleItem() {}

    const QString &theEntry() const { return m_theEntry; }
    void setTheEntry(const QString &theEntry) {
        if(m_theEntry != theEntry)
            Q_EMIT theEntryChanged(m_theEntry = theEntry);
    }

    // BaseClass interface
    QStringList someEntries() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    { return QStringList { m_theEntry }; }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void theEntryChanged(const QString &theEntry);

private:
    QString m_theEntry;
};
```

`MutliItem` stores a QStringList (for `someEntries`). I would like to write into that QStringList using the property defined in `BaseClass`. But I dont know how to add the WRITE option to the already defined Q_PROPERTY.

```
class MultiItem : public BaseClass {
    Q_OBJECT
    //Somehow add the setSomeEntries method to the property?

public:
    explicit MultiItem(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : BaseClass(parent) {}
    virtual ~MultiItem() {}

    void setSomeEntries(const QStringList &someEntries) {
        if(m_someEntries != someEntries)
            Q_EMIT someEntriesChanged(m_someEntries = someEntries);
    }

    // BaseClass interface
    QStringList someEntries() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE{ return m_someEntries; }

private:
    QStringList m_someEntries;
};
```

I cannot add the WRITE option in `BaseClass` because it would violate the meaning. Not every object of `BaseClass` allows setting that property but objects of `MultiItem` should be written only using that property.

Is this somehow possible without declaring a WRITE option to a `virtual ... = 0` in `BaseClass` that just logs a warning when called in `SingleItem`?

Comment: I think you should just add some method at `MultiItem` class for set `someEntries` values and mark this method  with `Q_INVOCABLE` and dont use property for changing values.